# Should I be able to assign in nested dictionaries in KDB?

Tags: kdb

According to the docs, the assignment of `lt below should have upsert mechanics:

```
s:()!()
s[`MSFT]:(`state`sym)!(`init`MSFT)

    | state sym
----| ----------
MSFT| init  MSFT
s[`MSFT][`lt]: 3

'assign
  [0]  s[`MSFT][`lt]: 3
                    ^
```

But instead I get an error.

Wham I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This goes back to the same problem you had before with typed dictionaries (dictionaries whose values are all the same type so kdb tries to keep it that way) - this time it's happening twice at two depths!

If you define:

```
s:()!()
s[`MSFT]:(`state`sym)!(`init`MSFT)
```

then kdb assumes the shape of the "values" based on your first insert to the dictionary. In this case, kdb enforces that any value in that dictionary (even the one for `MSFT`) is a dictionary with keys state and sym. That means you can't force a new shape on it by adding a third key (at least not in the way you're attempting to).

On top of that - the sub-dictionary that you've created is itself a typed dictionary whose values are all symbol so kdb will force it to stay symbol values (aka you can't suddenly make "3" a value).

The final issue here is the one Matthew pointed out - you can't assign using double brackets `[][]` you can only assign with one (and use depth if necessary).

Putting all of this together:

```
/define s to allow generic datatype
q)s:(1#`)!enlist[::]
/also don't allow the inner dictionary to be typed
q)s[`MSFT]:(``state`sym)!(::;`init;`MSFT)
/now you can assign
q)s[`MSFT;`lt]:3
q)s
    | ::
MSFT| ``state`sym`lt!(::;`init;`MSFT;3)
```

Answer (score 1):

A keyed table is a map from a table to a table, so what you're indexing in to `s` with needs to itself be a table. So

```
(enlist `) ! enlist `MSFT
```

Second, if you are starting with an empty keyed table, you need to enlist the key and value.

```
q)s: () ! ()
q)s[enlist (enlist `) ! enlist `MSFT]: enlist (`state`sym) ! `init`MSFT
q)s
    | state sym 
----| ----------
MSFT| init  MSFT
```

When your table is no longer empty, you don't need to enlist the key and value.

```
q)s[(enlist `) ! enlist `GOOG]: (`state`sym) ! `init`GOOG
q)s
    | state sym 
----| ----------
MSFT| init  MSFT
GOOG| init  GOOG
```

Comment: I get that, but what I'm trying to do is assign another column variable "lt". I was hoping that I could just create a non-conforming dictionary to manage application state. Thanks for your help btw!

Comment: Ah, I just re-read your question. This doesn't solve it, but generally when doing a nested update, you have to do it all in the same square brackets. So say you had a nested dictionary `d` you would have to update it with `d[a; b]: c` rather than `d[a][b]: c`

Comment: Trouble is, in my example above s[\`MSFT;\`lt]: 3 gives 'mismatch, which is surprising as \`lt isn't defined yet.

Comment: Yes, you can index into non-existent columns or entries of a dictionary in q, and it will usually just throw you nulls. So running `s[MSFT][lt]` willl just give you a null (in this case a symbol null). You can also index into something usng two sets of square brackets, but not update it using two sets of square brackets.

Comment: So in that case, how does one update a nested dictionary in that scenario then?

Comment: I think it might be a quirk of q working with tables (seeing as it transforms them into column dictionaries under the hood). You can update nested dictionaries just fine using your method. If we define a dictionary `d: \`a\`b ! (10; (\`c\`d ! 30 40))` then we can update a new key of the dict with `d[\`b; \`e]: 32`